# Apache-camel unzipping file brokes images

Tags: java, apache-camel, png, zip

Trying to unzip a file using Apache Camel. Zip file may contain several PNG images, several xml files. here is the code for unzipping, that I use:

```
ZipFileDataFormat zf = new ZipFileDataFormat();
    zf.setUsingIterator("true");

        from(InstanceInputFolderURL)
            .unmarshal(zf)     
            .split(bodyAs(Iterator.class))
                .streaming()
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                    .toD(InstanceOutputFolderURL+"/${file:onlyname.noext}")
                    .log("Unzipping file ${file:name} completed...")
                .end()
            .end()
```

As a result, I have all the contents of zip file in output directory.
XML files are ok. But all the PNG files are broken, they have incorrect size and cannot be displayed. Also I can see, that original PNG files are in ANSI, but extracted files are in UTF-8. I tried using ZipSplitter, but the result is the same.
How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: PNG files are not in ANSI, they are binary. You are converting the contents to `String`. That is not going to work. You need a `byte[]` of the original file contents.

Comment: @Ellot Frisch Thank you very much, convertBodyTo(byte[].class)  fixes the problem